# Change color of the Ocean in GeoRegionValuePlot

Tags: graphics, replacement, color, geography

I would like to know how to replace the color of the ocean, while keeping the borders between different countries, i.e. replace the blue into transparent color (see the figure).
I tried doing it with `ColorReplace`, but it also changes the colors of the borders.

Hera an example of the code:

```
vals={
 GeoVariant[Entity["Country", "Spain"], "SimplifiedArea"] -> 11.1268, 
 GeoVariant[Entity["Country", "Peru"], "SimplifiedArea"] -> 6.03548, 
 GeoVariant[Entity["Country", "Lithuania"], "SimplifiedArea"] -> 4.07754, 
 GeoVariant[Entity["Country", "Iraq"], "SimplifiedArea"] -> 2.19722, 
 GeoVariant[Entity["Country", "Libya"], "SimplifiedArea"] ->0.693147
}

plot = Show[
 GeoRegionValuePlot[vals, GeoRange -> {{-60, 90}, {-170, 190}}, ImageSize -> 900]]
```

[image]

Comment: `Show` isn't necessary, and hasn't been for a long time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking to do is to change the background of your image, and when you are looking for information on `GeoBackground` you need to know that it is often a proxy for `GeoStyling`. From the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoStyling.html), there are two styles added in v11 which accept additional direction: "Coastlines" and "CountryBorders". For example,

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[vals, GeoRange -> {{-60, 90}, {-170, 190}}, 
 GeoBackground -> {"CountryBorders", "Land" -> White, 
   "Ocean" -> LightBlue, "Border" -> Lighter@Gray}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but If I use the code GeoRegionValuePlot[vals, GeoRange -> {{-60, 90}, {-170, 190}}, GeoBackground -> {"CountryBorders", "Land" -> White, "Ocean" -> LightBlue, "Border" -> Lighter@Gray}]
I get the following image.
Any help? I'm running mathematica 10 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhFKe.png)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. If I use your code I get a map I attached in the answer. Any help?

Comment: Ah, yes, you must be using v10.4, or earlier. I'll make a note that my solution is v11+.

Comment: 10.4. Solution for that?@rcollyer

Comment: @GiorgioColangelo unfortunately, I don't have a good solution for it. I'll have to play with it to see if I can generate a better solution.